# How to create a sidebar menu in Bootstrap that retains state?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

If I have a controller - Destinations, with topbar menu with the same name. I'd like to have a left sidebar with Dest1, Dest2, Dest3 items that showup/hide when I click the Destinations top menu. However, I want the sidebar to stay visible all the time if I choose Dest1, Dest2 or Dest3 which are links to different views.  So far I have this in Destinations index view but but I don't want to repeat this below in every item in a sidebar menu.
I'd like to also sidebar item remained highlighted depending on what was selected. Topbar menu is defined in /-Layout view, should I put side bar there too? Thanks.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav  navbar-fixed-side navbar-fixed-side-left">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dest1", "Dest1", "Destinations")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dest2", "Dest2", "Destinations")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dest3", "Dest3", "Destinations")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

.....

Answer (score 6):

You can try with the below code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css?parameter=1"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <%--Add the css reference here--%>
    <link href="../css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper
        {
            left: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
                    </span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content" style="margin-top: 50px">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul id="sidebar_menu" class="sidebar-nav" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;
                padding-top: 10px">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#"><span id="main_icon" class="navbar-icon fa fa-bars icon">
                </span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Start Bootstrap </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <br />
            <br />
            <hr />
            <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2015 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the result

[image: And this is the result]

Comment: You forgot to mention where to get the simple-sidebar.css file. It is available for bootstrap 3&4 here https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

Comment: Would you please add the style that you have defined for the navbar-icon class too?

Comment: This is not a compleate answer

Answer (score 0):

[[You can get more details here in GitHub]](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar)

```
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });


    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
      padding-left: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
      padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
      z-index: 1000;
      position: fixed;
      left: 250px;
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: -250px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background: #000;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
      width: 250px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      margin-right: -250px;
    }


    /* Sidebar Styles */

    .sidebar-nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 250px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li {
      text-indent: 20px;
      line-height: 40px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
      height: 65px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 60px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
      color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background: none;
    }

    @media(min-width:768px) {
      #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 250px;
      }
      #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
      }
      #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            Start Bootstrap
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Overview</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-secondary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

        </div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


      </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```