# Left side nav bar on specific pages utilizing MVC model data for each page

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have utilized the code for a left side nav-bar [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158003/navigation-menu-on-the-left-side-with-close-and-open-button-in-asp-net-core-razo). However, I only need it to appear on specific pages. When it is present, I will need to pass data from the View model to the links in the nav bar in order to successfully navigate to the correct page selected.

Is there a best practice for this other than copy-pasting the code on each page? Seems like I could put the nav bar on _Layout.cshtml, have it appear on specified pages, then pass the data to the links either using MVC or jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the ASP.NET Core [view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2). In your `_Layout.cshtml`,  you add some logic to determine if you want to display the component, then you render it with the appropriate parameters.

Here's an example where the links are selected based on a name passed from the controller, but you can add any logic you need, including getting them from your database.

**HomeController.cs**

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // data to be passed to the component; 
       // will also be used to determine if the navbar should be displayed
        ViewData["NavMenuPage"] = "Index";
        return View();
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```cs
// condition to render the navigation menu 
@if (ViewData["NavMenuPage"] != null)
{
    // ASP.NET Core will search for a component named NavMenu, 
    // and invoke it with the provided data (here, the NavMenuPage set in the controller)
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("NavMenu", ViewData["NavMenuPage"])
}
```

**NavMenuViewComponent.cs**

Here, `NavMenu` is the name of your component, and the class name must be suffixed by `ViewComponent` for it to be found by ASP.NET Core. That class can be put anywhere in your project.

```cs
public class NavMenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string pageName)
    {
        var links = GetLinksForPage(pageName);
        return View(links);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetLinksForPage(string pageName)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> links = null;
        switch (pageName)
        {
            case "Index":
                links = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    { "Link 1", "https://www.google.com" },
                    { "Link 2", "https://www.example.com" },
                };

                break;

            case "Privacy":
                links = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    { "Link 3", "https://www.stackoverflow.com" },
                };

                break;
        }


        return links;
    }
}
```

**/Views/Shared/Components/NavMenu/Default.cshtml**

This is the code that will render your links. Note that this file can't be put anywhere: it has to follow certain naming conventions, as explained in the doc. Here, I put it in the shared folder.

```cs
// type of the object passed to View() call in NavMenuComponent.InvokeAsync
@model Dictionary<string, string>

<nav>
    @foreach (var link in Model)
    {
        <div><a href="@link.Value">@link.Key</a></div>
    }
</nav>
```

Comment: Excellent! I'll check out these docs and see how to best integrate this for my project.

Comment: I didn't use the ViewCompnents, but utilizing the ViewData to determine which page gets which nav menu helped out tremendously! Upvote for you, my friend!