# MVC Net Core Sidebar Navigation Menu Placing in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I created a simple MVC Net Core Default Project. I made some adjustments so it looks picture. Right now _Layout.cshtml only has top Navigation bar.

[image]

I want to add Left navigation bar, reading resource here. 
[how to create sidebar menu in bootstrap that stays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281993/How-to-create-sidebar-menu-in-bootstrap-that-stays). 
Where would I place it in cshtml file below? I tried placing around area below and did not work correctly.

```
<div class="container body-content">
@RenderBody() area,
```

Where would I place the Navbar code snippet in the cshtml below? Everytime I place it, it gets misaligned.

**Full _Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ElectronicsStore</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">  
        <div class="container-fluid">  
            <!--Navbar Header Start Here-->  
            <div class="navbar-header">  
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><font color="#fff"><b>Electronics</b></font></a>  
            </div>  
            <!--Navbar Header End Here-->  
            <!--Menu Start Here-->  
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <!--dropdown Menu Start-->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Technology
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">.NET</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASP.NET MVC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!--dropdown Menu End-->
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>  
            <!--Menu End Here-->  
            <!--Right Aligned Menu Start-->  
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
                <li><a href="#"><font color="#fff">Login</font></a></li>  
                <li><a href="#"><font color="#fff">Cart</font></a></li>  
            </ul>  
            <!--Right Aligned Menu End-->  
        </div>  
    </nav> 

    <div class="container body-content">
     // TRIED PLACING IT AROUND HERE, DOES NOT WORK
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2018 - ElectronicsStore</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Left SideBar Code to Place:**

```
 <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul id="sidebar_menu" class="sidebar-nav" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#"><span id="main_icon" class="navbar-icon fa fa-bars icon">
            </span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Start Bootstrap </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -- >
```

Comment: If you want the sidebar been displayed in all pages related with `_Layout.cshtml` you need to implement it in this layout.

Comment: Could you please see [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158003/navigation-menu-on-the-left-side-with-close-and-open-button-in-asp-net-core-razo) here ? If you still could not get the correct result , feel free to update me

Comment: Itminus this works, thanks-

Answer (score 3):

This is bootstrap 4 code for side menu.simply edit you layout.cshtml with the given code.

```js
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
```

```css
body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
      padding-left: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
      padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
      z-index: 1000;
      position: fixed;
      left: 250px;
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: -250px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background: #000;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
      width: 250px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      margin-right: -250px;
    }


    /* Sidebar Styles */

    .sidebar-nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 250px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li {
      text-indent: 20px;
      line-height: 40px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
      height: 65px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 60px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
      color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background: none;
    }

    @media(min-width:768px) {
      #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 250px;
      }
      #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
      }
      #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            Start Bootstrap
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Overview</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                 <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-secondary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

        </div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


      </body>
    </html>
```